# Plot for function that calculated direct with while, but is piecewise

Tags: plotting

For this question [Use of {FOR, Do, If,Plot} that ...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113940/use-of-for-do-if-plot-that-are-in-one-code), I wrote this code:

```
m = 3; 
t[-1] := 0
x[-1] := 0
Do[t[L] = 1 + 10*(1 - 0.9^L); Print["t[", L, "]=", t[L]], {L, 0, m}]
k = 0; While[k <= m, 
 Print["X_", k, "[t]=", 
   X[k][t_] = (1/2)*(-1 + 
       Sqrt[1 + 4*(t + ((1 + 2*x[k - 1])^2 - 1)/4)])]*
       Print["x_", k, "[t]=", 
   x[k] = Limit[X[k][t], t -> t[k], Direction -> 1]]; k++]
```

I need plot in piecewise distance `{t, t[-1], t[0]}`,`{t, t[0], t[1]}`,...,`{t, t[m-1], t[m]}`
Know I can not obtained plot in the following form:
[image]

Comment: Why are you multiplying two `Print` functions?

Comment: I'm afraid that I still can't understand your question, or your code. The code is fundamentally flawed, as Chuy mentioned as well. Do you need code to reproduce the plot you showed? Where did you obtain that plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[pw]
conds = # <= t <= #2 & @@@ Partition[t /@ Range[-1, 3], 2, 1];
vals = X[#][t] & /@ Range[0, 3];
pw[k_][t_] := Simplify[Piecewise[{{vals[[k + 2]], conds[[k + 2]]}}]]

Plot[Evaluate[pw[#][t] & /@ Range[-1, m - 1]], {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]